# How can i use expander as a child item of treeview in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, expander

I want to show a custom set of repeating datas

```
Class M

 prop1 // treeview heading

 List<String> // treeview items

 List<ClassSub> [ prop 1, porp2 ,List<String> sub items] //as an expander with List<String> as expander items

Class M

  prop1 // treeview heading

  prop2  // treeview items

  List<ClassSub>[prop1 ,prop2,List<String>...]//as an expander
```

Can i use a Treeview + Expander combination to arrange this complete set of data?

Or do i need to use a Codeplex librarys like http://complexdatatemplates.codeplex.com [But i dont see a clear documentation on   it]
[image: Sample structre is like it]

Comment: Yes you can. all you need to identify the need. could you post some screenshot of what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes quetion is editted with picture

Answer (score 1):

here is how I offer to solve your issue

xaml

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding TreeItems}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding SubItems}">
            <Expander Header="{Binding Header}">
                <ItemsControl Margin="25,0,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding TreeItems}" />
            </Expander>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Item class

```
class Item
{
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public List<string> TreeItems { get; set; }
    public List<Item> SubItems { get; set; }
}
```

View Model

```
class ViewModel 
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        TreeItems = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
        string[] data = new string[]{
                "Subchapter 1","Subchapter 2",
            };
        Item item = new Item()
        {
            Header = "Sub Getting Started",
            TreeItems = new List<string>(data)
        };

        TreeItems.Add(new Item()
        {
            Header = "Getting Started 1",
            SubItems = new List<Item>(new Item[] { item }),
            TreeItems = new List<string>(data)
        });
        TreeItems.Add(new Item()
        {
            Header = "Getting Started 2",
            SubItems = new List<Item>(new Item[] { item }),
            TreeItems = new List<string>(data)
        });
        TreeItems.Add(new Item()
        {
            Header = "Getting Started 3",
            SubItems = new List<Item>(new Item[] { item }),
            TreeItems = new List<string>(data)
        });
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Item> TreeItems { get; private set; }
}
```

result

[image: result]

In example above I haven't styled the Expander to match the one in screenshot posted in question. let me know if that is also required.

---

**EDIT**

as discussed, to display SubChapter1.1. and 1.2 to be visible by default or expand any other tree view item by default

start by defining a style for TreeViewItem in the resources

```
<TreeView.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
        <Setter Property="IsExpanded"
                Value="{Binding IsExpanded}" />
    </Style>
</TreeView.Resources>
```

add a property IsExpanded to BookChapter class

```
public class BookChapter
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public List<BookPage> pages { get; set; }
    //public List<Enrichment> enrichment { get; set; }
    public List<SubChapter> chapters { get; set; }

    public bool IsExpanded { get; set; }

}
```

then set IsExpanded to true if you want it to be initially expanded

```
BookChapter cha = new BookChapter { name = "Chapter Intro", pages = pags, IsExpanded=true };
```

result

[image: result]

you can control other tree items in a similar manner too.

---

**EDIT 2**

sample for the same using Listbox and data templates

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="chapterTemplate">
            <Expander Header="{Binding name}" IsExpanded="{Binding IsExpanded}">
                <StackPanel>
                    <ItemsControl Margin="25,0,0,0"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding pages}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Content="{Binding Path=label}">
                                </Button>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding chapters}"
                             BorderBrush="{x:Null}"
                             Margin="20,0,0,0" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Expander>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type l:BookChapter}">
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding}"
                            ContentTemplate="{StaticResource chapterTemplate}" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type l:SubChapter}">
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding}"
                            ContentTemplate="{StaticResource chapterTemplate}" />
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type l:BookPage}">
            <Button Content="{Binding Path=label}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}"
             Name="TOCView" />
</Grid>
```

result

[image: result]

with this approach you may not need to template the tree view item for the arrow. just template the expander as you wish

as a suggestion you can reuse BookChapter class as subchapters instead of creating a new class for SubChapter unless necessary.

Comment: As per suggestion i editted my code [ structre is like http://pastebin.com/KLi0j05a ]
And obtained result is @ question . I want SubChapter1.1. and 1.2 should also be visible by default

Comment: Yes to some extend. Can you suggest something [ link  or samples ] also ? For styling treeview header

Comment: [TreeView Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728671(v=vs.95).aspx), [TreeViewItem ControlTemplate Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms788727(v=vs.90).aspx), and last but not the least [TreeView and HierarchicalDataTemplate, Step-by-Step](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2009/10/30/treeview-and-hierarchicaldatatemplate-step-by-step.aspx)

Comment: I can also suggest that you may not require a treeview here for what you want to achieve. Listbox and expander are sufficient for the same.